# 凭, 按, 根据, 依据, 依照, and 按照 how to use these words correctly?

Tags: difference

All of these words mean "According to", but I'm wondering are there any different in use. For example, some of them might only be used as adj. or adv.; some of them might have other meanings.

Comment: I am too much tied up at the moment to give you an overview, but I suggest you query all of these terms on http://jukuu.com/ and http://www.iciba.com/ and try to find some differences based on the example sentences.

Comment: see 工具书（reference book）＂实用汉语近义虚词词典＂

Comment: none used as adj. or adv., possible uses:介（prep。），名（n。），动（v。）

Comment: ＂实用汉语近义虚词词典＂：依（介；动）／依据（介；名）／依照（介）［相同］都是介词，组成介词短语作状语，表示用某事物作为行为的前提或基础，相当于＂按照＂。＂依据＂和＂依照＂有时可以互换：１依据合同，你应当赔偿对方的损失。（依照✓依✕）２我相信法院会依据法律做出公正的判决。（依照✓依✕）３依照学校的规定，陈建国要被开除学籍。（依据✓依✕）４依照婚姻法，他们的婚姻是无效的。（依据✓依✕）［不同］１。＂依据＂主要表示在法律、规定或具体证据基础上进行，＂依据＂的一般是法律、规定等；＂依照＂主要表示按照原来的样子或情况进行，＂依照＂的可以是法律，规定，也可以是普通的事物，如习惯，计划、说法、意见等。＂依据＂一般都可以换成：＂依照＂，但＂依照＂不一定能换成＂依据＂：１依照惯例，中秋节要放三天假。（依据✓依✕）２这事别怪我，我可是依照老板的意思做的。（依据✓依✕）３把这件衣服拿去，依照原样再做一半。（依据✓依✕）４依照习惯，除夕晚上家家都要吃团圆饭。（依据✓依✕）５请依照规定的格式修改论文。（依据✓依✕）２。＂依＂一般用在单音节名词前，＂依据、依照＂不能和单音节词组合：＜＞依此类推 依法处理 依此入场 依样画葫芦 （依据✕依照✕） １此时，各国运动员正一次入场（依据✕依照✕）２法官必须公正，必须依法办事。（依据✕依照✕）３你就依样画葫芦，照着做就是了。（依据✕依照✕）

Comment: ３。＂依＂可组成＂依A说／看来＂的结构（A一人），表示从A的角度看问题；＂依据、依照＂无此用法：１依您说，这事怎么办？（依据✕依照✕）２依我说啊，大家都别去算了。（依据✕依照✕）３这事依我看没有问题。（依据✕依照✕）４。依我看来，林莉未必能找到更好的工作。（依据✕依照✕）４。＂依＂还有动词的用法，表示＂听从、顺从＂；＂依据、依照＂无此用法：１我依你，今天咱们就去看电影吧。（依据✕依照✕）２要依杨明的话，咱们现在早就赶上火车了。（依据✕依照✕）３杰克，你就依了大伙，和我们一起去跳舞吧。（依据✕依照✕）５。＂依据＂还有名词的用法，指事情发生的证据；还有动词的用法，表示用某个情况作为依据。＂依、依照＂无此用法：１你有什么依据说我拿了他的钱包？（依✕依照✕）２说话要有依据，不能乱说。（依✕依照✕）３你这么处理，依据的是哪条法律？（依✕依照✕）

Comment: 根据（介）／凭（介；连）［相同］都是介词，引出某种行为或某个结论的依据、基础。后边是＂什么、感觉、经验＂等词语时，常可互换：１他们根据什么得出这样的结论？（凭✓）２根据我的经验，明天肯定会下雨。（凭✓）３凭我的感觉，他不是越南人。（根据✓）４你凭什么说他是小偷？（根据✓）５你们凭什么做出这样的决定？（根据✓）［不同］１。＂凭＂主要引出某种行为所依靠的具体东西或某种能力。＂凭 A。。。＂表示依靠 A，进行某种行为或出现某种情况。A 一般是证件（工作征、学生征、身份征、车票、机票、电影票等）或能力、素质、经验等，而且 A 一般是属于主语自己的东西：１观众必须凭票入场。（＂票＂是＂观众＂的，根据✕）２我们凭学生征就可以买到此较便宜的车票。（＂学生征＂是＂我们＂的，根据✕）３凭我们现在的实力，要想打败他们很困难。（＂实力＂是＂我们＂的，根据✕）４我要凭自己的本事赚钱。（根据✕）５王明凭自己的努力创办了一家公司。（根据✕）６他凭什么能得优秀奖？（根据✕）２。＂根据＂主要引出进行某种行为的基础或依据，＂根据 A 。。。＂就是以 A 为基础，在这基础上再做某事或得出某个结论。A 不能是证件类的事物，A 一般不是属于主语自己的东西：

Comment: １我们根据学生的汉语水平，把他们分到不同的班级。（＂汉语水平＂不是＂我们＂的，凭✕）２根据学生的要求，学院这学期新开了三门选修课。（＂要求＂不是＂学院＂的，凭✕）３陈亮根据情况正确地做出了判断。（＂情况＂不是＂陈亮＂的，凭✕）４根据他指示的方向，我顺利地找到了邮局。（凭✕）５根据我的了解，他说的一切都是骗人的。（凭✕）６根据这条法律，他的行为已经构成犯罪。（凭✕）３。有时＂凭 A＂和＂根据 A＂相同，但意思不同，不能互换：＂凭 A＂表示某个人依靠自己的 A，可以怎么样；＂根据 A＂表示依据某人的 A，别人把这个人怎么样，或依据 A  会出现什么情况：１凭李明的能力，他管理一个小公司是没问题的。（李明可以怎么样，根据✕）２根据李明的能力，公司安排他去市场部工作。（公司把李明怎么样，凭✕）３凭我的水平，应该进中级班学习。（＂我＂可以怎么样，根据✕）４根据我的水平，老师把我安排到了中级班学习。（老师把＂我＂怎么样，凭✕）５凭我们的设计方案，我们应该能得到这个工程。（＂我们＂可以怎么样，根据✕）６根据我们的设计方案，这个工程应该在一年内完成。（出现什么情况，凭✕）４。＂凭＂可以组成＂凭着＂，＂根据＂不能：１小丽凭着一封信找到了她的妈妈。（根据✕）２凭着记忆，我找到了我的故乡。（根据✕）

Comment: 按（介）／按照（介）［相同］都是介词，组成介词短语作状语，引出行为的根据。常可互换：１按我说的去做，你就可以得到一份礼物。（按照✓）２出租车是按公里收费的。（按照✓）３《现代汉语词典》是按拼音字母的音序排列的。（按照✓）４按每人２个计算，至少应该准备１００个苹果。（按照✓）５按照一般的情况来说，这种药会有效的。（按✓）６按照她的能力和条件，完全可以担任国际裁判。（按✓）７按照你的成绩，你可以去中级班学习。（按✓）８任何人都必须按照学校的规定去做，不能特殊。（按✓）［不同］１。＂按＂后面可以是一些单音节词，＂按照＂后面不能是单音节词：１。租房要按月交租金。（按照✕）２自助餐是按人收费，每人１５０元。（按照✕）３学生名单按班排列，从初级班到高级班。（按照✕）４按理说，她应该向你道歉。（按照✕）２。＂按＂后面可以加＂着＂，＂按照＂不能：１按着金明珍留下的地址，我们顺利地找到了她家。（按照✕）２请大家按着名单的顺序一个一个发言，每人５分钟。（按照✕）３只要你按着我说的方法做，就不会有问题。（按照✕）４我是按着模特身上的衣服做的，怎么样？。（按照✕）
also see previous Q about 按照（似乎没有重叠）

Comment: @user6065 Thank you so much for your answer. It's really useful. 感谢你!

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two ways to answer your question. I'm not sure which would be more helpful to you:

1) an etymological answer: why are these particular words being used in this particular way;

2) a grammatical answer: what syntactic differences exist between the words; what different kinds of sentences are they used in.

For me, I often find the etymological answer is more useful, in that I get more of a sense of what the speaker is thinking. Grammar often does not help that much in illuminating what someone is thinking, though it is essential for using the word correctly yourself.

I'll try the etymological approach here, and look at what 按, 照, 依, 憑, 根, and 據 are doing here.

按 = to press with the finger; imagine the judge running a finger down a list of rules.
依 = to lean on; to rely on something to hold you in a set position.
照 = to illuminate; in fact, this is a key word: you could take it to mean 'according to' all by itself, with modifications indicated by what's in front: 依照,  按照 are variations of 照; they both rely on light to some degree

憑 seems to be 'rely on' in a mental sense; it is closer to 靠 in meaning than 依. Of all the words here, 憑 is the furthest removed from the central meaning of 'according to'.

根 means root; in a more fig. or adverbial sense, it means to take something as a base, what something is built on
據 is another key word; it originally meant to support oneself with a staff. Light is not necessary for this. If one's staff is touching the ground (rooted, 根據) one knows one has a solid basis for action. One can also lean on one's staff 依據, and avoid slipping.

So basically there are two ideas here:
 
照 is to follow something that illuminates one's way.  This is often realized as following someone's rules, methods, or example.
據 is to have a fixed point that allows one to act without mishap. This often suggests the idea of a basis for one's actions or beliefs

These two basic ideas can be modified by appropriate forms. 依 works with both 照 and 據; on the other hand 按 doesn't work with 據 (why press on a staff with one finger?) and 根 doesn't work with 照 (what is the basis of a lamp?)

This is what I see as the semantics involved; for grammar, the comment under your answer has perhaps more useful guidance.